# Separate November 29 org-9.5.1 directory under elpa directory

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, use-package

I just noticed that I have under my `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory a `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.5.1/` directory wherein all the entries have the date `29 Nov`. So when I look for `ob-haskell.el` it's not in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, rather, in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.5.1/`. What also seems odd is this

```
(use-package ob-haskell
  :ensure t)
```

in my init produces this error

```
Error (use-package): Failed to install ob-haskell: Package ‘ob-haskell-’ is unavailable
```

What am I dealing with here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ob-haskell.el` is expected to be inside the org-9.5.1 directory, so if it is missing then perhaps you deleted it. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the package.

The date on the files just means that you installed the package on the 29th of November.

Comment: As I said, it is in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.5.1/`. But it's not in a package archive as a stand-alone that I have set up (ELPA, gnu, melpa); `list-package` doesn't know it. I just restarted with `(require 'ob-haskell)` and haskell babel is working. So the `use-package ob-haskell...` must apply only for members of my listed package archives, that `ob-haskell` is an org "built-in" now and org must know where it is. Correct me if I'm wrong about any of this.